# If Dot product of $\mathbf{a}(t)$ and derivative of $\mathbf{b}(t)$ is negative implies dot product itself is negative with some conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, vectors, inner-products

Given two vectors $\mathbf{a}(t) = (r(t), s(t), -v(t), -u(t))$ and $\mathbf{b}(t) = (p(t), q(t), w(t), z(t))$, along with accompanying conditions:

1. $r(t) + s(t) - v(t) - u(t) \leq 0$
2. $r(t)p'(t) + s(t)q'(t) -v(t)w'(t) - u(t)z'(t) \leq 0$ (Dot product of $\mathbf{a}(t)$ and derivative of $\mathbf{b}(t)$)
3. $p(t) + z(t) \leq q(t) + w(t)$ or $p(t) + z(t) - q(t) - w(t) \leq 0$

My intuition says the dot product of $\mathbf{a}(t)$ and $\mathbf{b}(t)$ will be negative. I could not prove it anyway.

Is there a more general formulation or further conditions to consider before this statement can be held?

Note: Here each p(t), q(t), w(t), z(t), r(t), s(t), v(t) and u(t) are positive real valued functions of t.

Comment: $\mathbf b'(t)$ need not hold any particular relation to $\mathbf b(t)$. So 2 doesn't tell you anything of use about the relationship between $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ for any fixed value of $t$. It is completely irrelevant to your question. The most restrictive - and therefore most important - information in the entire post was given in your Note tacked on at the very end. It restricts $\bf a, b$ to two "quadrants" (I'm not sure what the correct terminology for $\Bbb R^4$ would be). Conditions 1 and 3 then further restrict them to half of their respective "quadrants".

Comment: @Al.G. Sorry, It is a typo. It should have been "I could not prove it anyway".

Comment: @PaulSinclair I tried to generalize the technique of an author in his research paper. You can see from one of my problems posted (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4879628/745447). Also, could you please explain in a different way or a bit more I'm not understanding your explanation.

Comment: Your intuition is false. $\mathbf a = (1,1,-1,-1), \mathbf b = (1,1,0.1, 0.1)$ has $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = 1.8 > 0$. Conditions 1 and 3 are satisfied as are the conditions in your Note. To meet condition 2, let $\bf a$ be constant and set $\mathbf b(t) = (1-t, 1-t, (0.1)(1-t),(0.1)(1-t))$.